How to fix cabinet paint work?
Around a year ago, we decided to paint our cabinets. We went to a box hardware store and asked for help since we were novices. These were factory-made wood ones with what I think was varnish over stained wood.
They told us to do the following:

Use liquid sandpaper chemical to strip varnish
Lightly sand the cabinets.
Prime (they gave us an acrylic-based primer)
Paint (they gave us an enamel cupboard paint)

Unfortunately, it didn’t turn out. The enamel paint never hardened, and even a year later, you can leave a mark in the pant with your fingernail. The enamel is soft, and even wiping it down removed it, showing the white primer underneath.
From what I read, acrylic cannot be used under enamel, and now I’m wondering how I’m going to fix this.
Is it correct that the paint might not be compatible? How do I best strip it and avoid this issue next time?
https://imgur.com/a/66wXwyA

Unfortunately, it sounds like you need to strip the finish again.  Was the original finish in poor condition, or just not to your taste?

It wasn't in horrible condition at all, but it was dated by a few decades and we wanted something more modern. Is there anything special i need to do to strip the enamel/acrylic combo? If you have any product or method recommendations I'm open for comment :D

Not sure, we're not really supposed to provide product recommendations.  But Citristrip or a similar citrus-based paint stripper may work for you.  It may be more about procedure than product, in terms of ensuring you allow the product sufficient time to work properly.
